# Bash script not running

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So I'm pretty new to ubuntu and I'm trying to make a simple bash script that all it does is running Rubymine so I don't have to write it down in the command line everytime and also so I can have it on the desktop. The code I have in there is:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo 'opt/Ruby Mine/bin/rubymine.sh'
```

It is marked to execute as a program but everytime I try to open it it just opens with gedit.

Comment: How are you trying to open it?

Comment: By the way, for best results it should look like:      #!/bin/sh <enter here> sudo '/opt/Ruby Mine/bin/rubymine.sh'

Comment: double pressing it :P @waltinator

Comment: You could always use a .desktop file as you are only running one command.  Just copy an existing file and change the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Nautilus, Top menu, `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Behaviour`

Change `View executable text files when they are opened` to either `Run executable text files when they are opened` (warning:  Potentially dangerous!) or `Ask each time`

Comment: Thanks, but why is it potentially dangerous? Is it because I can download some file that can harm my computer?

Comment: Right.  If you somehow end up putting an executable file that you don't know the contents of somewhere and double-clicking it...you'll end up executing it!  

Only you can decide if that's worth the risk to you or not.  I wouldn't personally worry about it, hence only **potentially** dangerous (if you're in the habit of double-clicking executables you don't know!)

Comment: Well now it opens but for some reason as soon as I enter the password it closes and doesn't open the program :P can you help me with that too?

Comment: It really depends what the rubymine.sh does.  The terminal will close as soon as execution is done.  Try putting  a read statement after the rubymine command:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause